# Unable to retrieve lead data from Facebook in my local CRM

Tags: facebook

I want to get all the lead information related to all the form in my campaign in the Facebook lead ads management, how can i improve my below code to get the Facebook lead data.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';
use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Http\Response;
use FacebookAds\ApiRequest;
use FacebookAds\Object\LeadgenForm;
use FacebookAds\Object\Page;
use FacebookAds\Object\Lead;
use FacebookAds\Object\Ad;
use FacebookAds\Cursor;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdReportRunFields;
use FacebookAds\Http\Request;
$api = api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $user_access_token);
$accounts = Api::instance();
$page = new Page($my_page_id);
$leadgen_forms = $page->getLeadgenForms();
foreach($leadgen_forms as $forms){
    $data = $forms->getData();
    $csv_url = $data['leadgen_export_csv_url'];
    //print "<a href='".$csv_url."' title='download'>Download &nbsp;". 
    $data['name']." Data</a><br/>";
    $form_id = $data['id'];
    $form = new LeadgenForm($form_id);
    $form_content = $form->getLeads();
    //var_dump($form_content);
    print_r($form_content);
}
```

I have used all the function available in the lead API.